# Extremely confusing (And infuriating) PHP/HTML problems

Tags: php, html

I've been running into some extremely confusing problems lately.

For example I'll have a code. Like this:

```
  echo "<ID>" . $daten->Firma_ID . "</ID><Name>" 
  . str_replace(array("&", "<", ">", "\"", "'"), 
  array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;"), 
  $daten->Name_1. ' '. $daten->Name_2.", ". $daten->Ort) 
  ."</Name>";
```

This is to escape symbols in a string to HTML codes. (& -> & amp;)

Now what this OUTPUTS me though is literally "& amp;". Sometimes.

Further up in the code I use the same method (The exact same code), just that it works perfectly fine there. This is really frustrating.

Could there be any reason for this? Also, this happens on all browsers (Tested IE, Chrome and Firefox)

EDIT: interesting to note is that if I change &amp into something like &szlig (ß) that works fine as well. This seems to happen only with &amp at that specific time.

Comment: Is `& amp;` what the browser shows you or what is in the generated source code? I could imagine that it is replaced twice: `&` => `&amp;`=> `&amp;amp;`, which would be displayed by the browser as `&amp;` again.

Comment: You should learn something about proper code formatting. Maybe read this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html It's on `zend` website but it's applicable to `PHP` in general.

Comment: @Gerald I think this might actually be the case.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Yeah maybe, I know this doesn't look too pretty but don't worry, the rest of the code is pretty neatly formatted. ;)

Comment: @Eskir you should really use the htmlentities function as suggested by ElmoVanKielmo.

Comment: This problem should be easily reproducible when spotted; do you have a particular `$daten` object that causes it?

Comment: Apparently htmlentities also gives me a literal "&amp ;" (minus the space, of course). This is still frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

You are reinventing the wheel - just use:

```
$str_with_entities = htmlentities($str);
```

as [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) says.

You can also nest this call if you want the browser to display `$amp;`:

```
$str_with_entities = htmlentities(htmlentities($str));
```

Comment: Still returns "&amp ;" (minus the space). I'm wanting to hit my head on the table now.

Comment: I need the browser to show me `&`. The source code says `&amp;` but so does the browser.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to escape HTML output is by using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
$id = $daten->Firma_ID;
$name = "{$daten->Name_1} {$daten->Name_2} {$daten->Ort}";

printf('<ID>%s</ID><Name>%s</Name>',
  htmlspecialchars($id, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
  htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
);
```

*The use of `printf()` is my personal preference to make my code clearer.*

Comment: +1 for you. Generally OP can pick your `htmlspecialchars()` or mine `htmlentities()` depending on real needs.